# load bank: 12V, 120 A

Tags: arduino, pid-controller

I'm trying to design a load bank with a power source of 12V. I want to get a range of Amps in the output (from 1 Amp to 120 Amps, so that is 1 amp, 2 amps, 3 amps,…120amps) and I want it to be controlled by Arduino.

I already came up with the design, which is basically a combination of 8 MOSFETs and the resistors to get the needed current. By combining them, I can get up to 120 Amps.

My problem starts now. Since the power is coming from a battery, the voltage will fluctuate. Therefore, I won’t get the current I was looking for, thus the current will be lower or higher depending on the value of voltage.
These are the solutions I came up with:

- Apply sort of voltage regulator. (I am not really sure about this, because I’ve been looking around and there are available in the market but they are not allow more than 1 amps).
- Design a PID current controller. (I think this should be the best option, but a tricky one though).
  I have been trying to do it with a PID, but I’ve spent two days trying to design it and to be honest, I’m quite lost. Could you shed some light if any of you think that the PID is the solution?

I’m looking for a maximum error of 0.5 amps.

Comment: Your design is a constant load resistor. If you look up load banks that do constant current, they adjust their load resistance so that the current is constant. If you're trying to keep it simple, using a micro processor and 8 FETs, I think you'll struggle to get the control for that large a range of currents.

Comment: Stating the obvious, really, but have you realised you'll be needing to get rid of almost 1500W of heat somehow?

Comment: And why do you think a) you need a PID, and b) that a PID controller can't oscillate?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a load that automatically adapts to different source voltages, so that the power converted in that load to heat is constant.

Typically, you'd implement something like that using transistors, which you control accordingly.

So, yes, you'll need some form of controller; a feedback loop seems highly desirable.

In this scenario, it's probably easiest to use a set of MOSFETs as the load "resistors". Since the whole math is *really* easy,

$$P =U\cdot I\text,$$

you can basically just write a loop that decreases the effective resistance of your MOSFETs (by increasing the gate voltage in an N-channel mosfet, typically) until you hit your "should be" power point. Of course, having a fully fledged PID controller is a much better approach, avoiding oscillations, but this all comes down to how much faster you can control the MOSFET than your power source is going to change.

Now, practically:

- 12 V · 120 A = 1.44 kW. You need to get **this frigging amount of heat** out of your transistors in order for them to not burn. Good luck with that.
- That's still 180 W per MOSFET if you have 8.
- To allow 12 V to push 120 A through a system, that system needs to have an effective resistance of 0.1 Ω. That makes finding MOSFETs that can both do those currents and an Rds_on low enough to fulfill that expensive.
- A PCB trace designed to carry 120 A over 10 cm, not allowed to get more than 40 °C hotter by itself (not counting hot transistors) of 70µm copper (twice what you find on most PCB) would have to be 4.8cm wide. That's a layout challenge right there; the narrower the traces, the higher the inherent resistance (making the previous point harder to achieve)
- Please consider the voltage spikes that a few nH of parasitic inductivity would induce if you suddenly turn of the 120 A (e.g. for automatic shutdown in case of overtemperature). Not pretty, at all.
- 120 A really sounds like you should an expert design this stuff. The amount of sharp stuff that might explode and fly around is really not to be underestimated at these currents.

Comment: A very confused answer. If the load is actually a resistance, then the heat is dissipated in the load resistance and not the FET, which would be in saturation. If the FET is not in saturation, RDS(on) has no meaning when you are using a FET as the load dissipater.   You can get FETs that will dissipate these types of power levels ....an example being the IXTK90N25L2 (http://ixapps.ixys.com/DataSheet/DS100080(IXTK-TX90N25L2).pdf). These are designed to tolerate this type of application, here's a video showing a 1 kW electronic load with these devices https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vr6YsT403DM

Comment: @JackCreasey I was assuming that for max current, he'd drive the the MOSFET to minimum R, hence my RDS(on) consideration (of course, for everything above, that does not count, but nor does it matter).

Answer (score 2):

Let's get the specs right: a 0-120A current sink with input voltage compliance of 10-14V.

Dissipating all this power in one component is a bad idea, so we will split it into, say, 10-20 amp modules which will then be placed in parallel. Here is such a module:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWQO30.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is simple: a DAC creates a control voltage (VRef), then an opamp controls a MOSFET in source follower mode. Vref appears on the known load resistor, therefore current is I = Vref/R.

You can mix this solution with Finbarr's, by using a constant voltage for Vref and turn each module on and off.

A large team of 50c dual channel opamps and $1 FETs will usually beat a very expensive, huge MOSFET on both price and maximum dissipation, due to heat being less concentrated in a single point and thus easier to get rid of.

Now, using N-channel MOSFETs has a drawback: you will need a higher power supply to drive the gates. But it has an advantage too: you can solder all the drains of your NMOS'es to a big chunk of copper bar which doubles as a power rail, and will have much better heat transfer to the final heatsink.

You see, a TO220 (or similar) FET's maximum power is quite limited by the electrical insulator separating it from the heat sink, because the area at the back of a TO220 isn't that large.

If you get FETs with RthJC around 0.7-1°C/W, the silpad at the back will add about as much thermal resistance (if not more)... solder conducts heat much better, and the surface area of silpad you can use between the big copper bar and the actual heat sink is much larger.

You can also use a live heatsink (at +12V) but since this is most likely gonna be watercooled... probably better to ground it to avoid electrolysis.

Now, the power dissipation will be split between MOSFET and resistor.

[image]

So, max power is at Vin=14V and I=10A

Presistor = 100W
PFet = 40W

Max power for MOSFET occurs when input voltage is equally split between resistor and FET, thus at Vin=14V it occurs at I=7A and both components dissipate 49W.

With 1°C/W between your FET die and water at 50°C, die will reach 100°C so you're good to go.

Add a big 100W-150W power resistor. Check prices, maybe you'd be better off dissipating most of the power in FETs and only use a current sense shunt for the resistor.

Or, if you use imprecise resistors (like a water boiler resistor or a coil of resistive wire) put a current measuring shunt in series, so the opamp controls the current using the shunt, but the power is dissipated in the big resistor.

If you do not want to use water cooling... well good luck man! The cheapest option would be like a hair dryer: very hot resistive wire, and very strong fan.

*** PLAN B**

If you're only interested in AVERAGE current consumed by your load, then you can use PWM and not dissipate much power inside the FETs. In this case, resistors go into the FET drains as usual.

You'll need 5-10 parallel low-RdsOn NMOS and a huge power resistor, most likely DIY with resistive wire.

But your current will be chopped, and I believe this is not what you want, so I won't elaborate on that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is perfectly achievable as long as you find a way of getting rid of nearly 1500W of heat. Obviously that's at maximum load, so you'll need to consider just how long the device will be operating under various load conditions and plan a water or forced air cooling system accordingly.

In theory, you only need to build seven current sinks: 1A, 2A, 4A, 8A, 16A, 32A and 64A and turn them on in the right combination. The challenging ones, of course, are the higher values. Assumming you want to support a battery voltage down to say, 10V, you'll need a MOSFET with an ON resistance of 0.156 Ohms at 64A for the last one and that's probably going to be a challenge, especially if you add in a sense resistor to monitor the current.

16A, however, means a total resistance of MOSFET and sense resistor of 0.625 Ohms, which is more realistic.

So I would probably go for 1A, 2A, 4A, 8A and then seven 16A sinks, giving you a maximum of 127A if you want. Build each sink separately, connect the battery to a pair of large copper busbars and wire each sink seperately in between them. The 16A sinks will generate a significant but manageable 192W each at 12V.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple to build an electronic load that will handle 120 A plus and be insensitive to the terminal voltage. You do not need a PID at all. You simply need a constant current load.
I suggest you read [this](http://www.edn.com/design/analog/4368416/Design-a-100A-active-load-to-test-power-supplies) as a great introduction to electronic loads. The schematics here are a little complex, but you can simplify this with modern components such as the  [IXTK TX90N25L2](http://ixapps.ixys.com/DataSheet/DS100080(IXTK-TX90N25L2).pdf) I referenced in the comments.

The major element to understand is that dissipation of power in an active device is subject to special considerations for the SOA at DC. Most FETs are very limited in the DC SOA, so even if you use many it can be a difficult problem to solve. 
Read [this](http://www.ixys.com/Documents/AppNotes/IXAN0068.pdf) and [this](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon+-+Application+Note+-+PowerMOSFETs+-+OptiMOS%E2%84%A2+-+Linear+Mode+Operation+and+SOA+Power+MOSFETs.pdf?fileId=db3a30433e30e4bf013e3646e9381200) describing the problems.

To use an Arduino you are going to need a voltage reference (TL431), DAC(TI DAC7571) and multiple power FETs (though you probably need no more than 2-3 in your application) and drivers.

Creating the load is significantly easier than dissipating all that energy (close to 1500 W). You will need a huge heatsink/fan to allow the load to run for any length of time, so you might be better using a liquid coolant system.
With 5 gallons of water it would take 30 minutes to raise the temperature by 30 degC. If you run a loss system at 5 gallons per hour then you could run for several hours continuously.